# OpenJDK platform binary consuming too much ram

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm coding flutter in vs code and i have noticed that OpenJDK platform binary consuming too much ram and it's not about that only
It's consuming my cpu to.

[Task manager screenshot About 1 gb of ram !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ecI0.jpg)

Why is this? And how yo fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I've did a bit of search and this issue isn't uncommon and doesn't seem to be uniquely caused by Flutter specifically https://www.google.com/search?q=openjdk+high+memory+usage

Have you tried using the latest version of either Flutter stable or master channels and see if the same behavior persists? If yes, I suggest filing this as an issue here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues with a complete repro to replicate.